# How can I find references of a class in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I have a java class in my project, how can I find all of the places it's being used? Similar to Visual Studios find references.

Thanks.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Put the mouse cursor/caret on the class or method name in source code and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>.

Comment: do you know by any chance the equivalent of this in EMacs once you've set up your ETags?

Answer (score 11):

1. Right-click the class in project explorer, or in the editor
2. Select `References -> Project` (or the other options, if they fit your case better)

Answer (score 7):

Just a follow up since I was looking for all references for ALL public methods of a class in Eclipse:

- Open the class in the editor
- Open the Outline view
- select all the methods you want to analyze
- Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>

This gives call hierarchy results for each method you selected. Hope this helps!

Edit: used the actual LIST item formatter

Comment: Thanks a lot!
This one helped a lot