# How to find which method calls currently selected method in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

In Eclipse, when you click on a method name and press the <kbd>F3</kbd> button, it takes you to that method.

How can I do the reverse of this?  I have a method that's overloaded (probably about 12 different instances of it), and I would like to quickly find if this particular one is being called from anywhere else.

I know you can click on the method, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>H</kbd>, and Search for this `Method` in the `Workspace`.  Is there a simpler keyboard shortcut for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I find references of a class in Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839156/how-can-i-find-references-of-a-class-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Click on the method and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to perform a Search for `References in Workspace`.

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> opens the Call Hierarchy, which sounds like what you're looking for.

Comment: Louis, do you know which is more efficient -- the Search or the Call Hierarchy?  Both of them are giving the expected results.

Comment: The Call Hierarchy seems more specific -- it opens up the methods that _call_ this specific method, so I'd assume it's more relevant.  I think, for example, that References in Workspace includes documentation references, whereas the call hierarchy does not.